# How to implement a simple assertion macro in C?

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to implement my own macro assertion for learning purposes. The problem is I don't manage evaluate an expression at compile time (a compile-time evaluable expression of course) and to write a message at compile time in stdout/stderr. How does `<assert.h>` manage to do that?
What I tried so far is a structure like:

```
#define MY_ASSERT(_EXPR) (\
#IF (_EXPR)
// don't know how to tell preprocess to write a message
#ENDIF \
)
```

but it is clearly wrong syntactically and maybe conceptually.

Comment: you can use `#error` for that

Comment: `#IF` and `#ENDIF` meaningless (erroneous) in C (with lower-case spelling, they might be meaningful, but not in the body of a macro).   Static assertions (`_Static_assert` aka `static_assert`) are evaluated at compile time; ordinary assertions are evaluated at runtime.  For ordinary (dynamic?) assertions, you need the macro to expand to an expression.  You'll need to use the stringize operator `#` to get the text of the expression into the message.  You'll probably use a function to do the printing, rather than calling `fprintf()` or anything similar directly in the macro.